# "Application not installed" in other devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a beginner to android studio. I've build an app and tested it in my phone using USB debugger. but I'm getting `Application not installed` message while trying to installing it in other devices. What i have to do for install it in other phones?

Comment: did you run the app using hot run in your device ?

Comment: Which is your device and what is its android version?

Comment: my phone is lenovo A1000 and android version is 5.0. and im not aware of hot run exactly, running it instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This issue comes when you just install the build which was generated while running app directly by adb.**

> To overcome this issue **Make build from Android Studio> Build > Build
>   Apk**. A popup at bottom right will appear when build apk finish task.

You can find this generated apk inside `YourApp>build>outputs>apk`.

**Reason :**

When you run app directly by adb via usb cable. Then Android just pick the libraries for only your device. That build will not be valid some time for other devices.

Now when you use **Build Apk Tool**. Then actually this build is global build with all the required libraries inside it.

Comment: thanks a lot, after this build what i've to do for getting the apk?

Comment: You can find this generated apk inside YourApp>build>outputs>apk.

Comment: I have mentioned that in answer dude :)

Comment: i got the apk but when i share it via whatsapp it shows a zip file.

Comment: It is apk type file in your folder?

Comment: It does not happen with me, I send apk on whatsapp many times.
What you can do is, send apk via email.

Comment: but the app name is changed from what i've labelled it. in folder it shows app-debug.apk

Comment: Or apk go in zip format, see what the receiver get?

Comment: app-debug is default name, when you build apk. This is normal behavior.

Comment: yeah,done! i've mailed it and it is installed in other phone. thanks a lot. :)